# Using R - frequency counts with variable binwidths and factors

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I have quite a large dataset (over 1 million rows) of which a small sample is here:

```
structure(list(Feret = c(0.017, 0.016, 2.12, 0.016, 0.02, 0.023, 
0.017, 0.021, 0.02, 0.016, 0.027, 0.052, 0.061, 0.033, 0.041, 
0.017, 6.561, 7.123, 0.027, 0.018, 0.024, 4.099, 0.022, 0.025, 
0.037, 0.037, 0.018, 0.039, 0.027, 0.053, 0.016, 0.107, 0.52, 
0.041, 0.038, 0.039, 0.03, 0.071, 0.022, 0.118, 0.032, 0.018, 
0.027, 0.035, 8.113, 0.078, 4.089, 0.035, 0.057, 6.905, 2.5, 
0.282, 0.045, 0.039, 0.071, 0.037, 0.029, 0.027, 0.016, 0.02, 
0.026, 0.025, 0.026, 0.016, 0.016, 0.021), sample.type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("flower", "leaf"), class = "factor"), leaf.side = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("lower", "upper"), class = "factor"), canopy = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("bottom", "top"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("blue", "green", "grey", "white", "yel-green"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Feret", "sample.type", "leaf.side", 
"canopy", "treatment"), row.names = c(500000L, 500001L, 500002L, 
500003L, 500004L, 500005L, 500006L, 500007L, 500008L, 500009L, 
500010L, 800000L, 800001L, 800002L, 800003L, 800004L, 800005L, 
800006L, 800007L, 800008L, 800009L, 800010L, 1000L, 1001L, 1002L, 
1003L, 1004L, 1005L, 1006L, 1007L, 1008L, 1009L, 1010L, 10000L, 
10001L, 10002L, 10003L, 10004L, 10005L, 10006L, 10007L, 10008L, 
10009L, 10010L, 100000L, 100001L, 100002L, 100003L, 100004L, 
100005L, 100006L, 100007L, 100008L, 100009L, 100010L, 1160000L, 
1160001L, 1160002L, 1160003L, 1160004L, 1160005L, 1160006L, 1160007L, 
1160008L, 1160009L, 1160010L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have been trying to create frequency counts of the 'Feret' variable with the following binswidths:

```
bins <- c(0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1,3,10)
```

and then using:

```
freq<-hist(df_temp$Feret, breaks=bins)
ranges<-paste(head(bins,-1),bins[-1],sep=" - ")
freq$counts
df5<-data.frame(ranges = ranges, frequency = freq$counts)
df5
```

But what I really need to do is split the data.frame up by the various factors ("sample.type","leaf.side","canopy", "treatment") and extract frequency counts for each subset.
I can do this the long winded way by manually creating each subset but I would like to do it a better way. I've tried using loops to create the subsets and then apply the hist() function to each subset, but it was taking a very long time. Is there a better way using Dplyr or Apply?
I'd prefer to just to have the results in a table and then I can plot them as required.

Comment: Perhaps something like `df %>% mutate(Feret = cut(Feret, breaks = bins)) %>% count_(., names(.))`?

Comment: Something like `table(cut(df$Feret, bins))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet should do what you want:

I loaded your sample into `df`.

```
library("dplyr")
df %>% group_by(sample.type, leaf.side, canopy, treatment) %>%
  dplyr::select(Feret) %>%
  do(data.frame(table(cut(.$Feret, breaks=bins, include.lowest=T))))
```

I refer you to the [dplyr documentation](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html). In short, `x %>% f` is `f(x)` and `x -> f(a)` is `f(x,a)`.

Note that `dplyr::select` is just `select`, but I have had namespace issue so many times that now I always specify the package.

`table(cut(df$Feret, breaks=bins))` is just a nicer way to do what you did with `hist`. With `cut`, you create a factor variable (Remember to add include.lowest=T if your values can reach the lower bound) and with `table`, you count the frequency of each level.

This gives:

```
   sample.type leaf.side canopy treatment        Var1 Freq
1       flower     upper    top     green (0.01,0.03]    0
2       flower     upper    top     green  (0.03,0.1]    6
3       flower     upper    top     green   (0.1,0.3]    1
4       flower     upper    top     green     (0.3,1]    0
5       flower     upper    top     green       (1,3]    1
6       flower     upper    top     green      (3,10]    3
7       flower     upper    top     white (0.01,0.03]    4
8       flower     upper    top     white  (0.03,0.1]    4
9       flower     upper    top     white   (0.1,0.3]    0
10      flower     upper    top     white     (0.3,1]    0
11      flower     upper    top     white       (1,3]    0
12      flower     upper    top     white      (3,10]    3
13        leaf     lower bottom     white (0.01,0.03]    5
14        leaf     lower bottom     white  (0.03,0.1]    4
15        leaf     lower bottom     white   (0.1,0.3]    1
16        leaf     lower bottom     white     (0.3,1]    1
17        leaf     lower bottom     white       (1,3]    0
18        leaf     lower bottom     white      (3,10]    0
19        leaf     lower    top      grey (0.01,0.03]   10
20        leaf     lower    top      grey  (0.03,0.1]    1
21        leaf     lower    top      grey   (0.1,0.3]    0
22        leaf     lower    top      grey     (0.3,1]    0
23        leaf     lower    top      grey       (1,3]    0
24        leaf     lower    top      grey      (3,10]    0
25        leaf     upper bottom     white (0.01,0.03]    4
26        leaf     upper bottom     white  (0.03,0.1]    6
27        leaf     upper bottom     white   (0.1,0.3]    1
28        leaf     upper bottom     white     (0.3,1]    0
29        leaf     upper bottom     white       (1,3]    0
30        leaf     upper bottom     white      (3,10]    0
31        leaf     upper    top      blue (0.01,0.03]   10
32        leaf     upper    top      blue  (0.03,0.1]    0
33        leaf     upper    top      blue   (0.1,0.3]    0
34        leaf     upper    top      blue     (0.3,1]    0
35        leaf     upper    top      blue       (1,3]    1
36        leaf     upper    top      blue      (3,10]    0
```

(Actually, it doesn't print like this since this is a tbl, but you can use print.data.frame to print a tbl the old way.)

From here it should be straightforward to extract the info you want.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly. Thank you. Now that's given me a taste for dplyr, I'll go and have a read through the documentation and see if i can find a tutorial. It doesn't look so daunting now I see your snippet of code and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Start by defining a character vector with the factor names:

```r
factors <- c("sample.type","leaf.side","canopy", "treatment")
```

Then use this vector to apply the `hist()` function to each factor (the data is assumed to be stored in a data frame object called `df`):

```r
res <- sapply(factors, function(factor) {
  lapply(split(df[, c("Feret", factor)], df[[factor]]), function(group) {
    hist(group$Feret, breaks = bins, plot = FALSE)
  })
}, simplify = FALSE)
```

You now have a list with one element for each factor, each of which is again a list with an element for each level:

```
> names(res)
[1] "sample.type" "leaf.side"   "canopy"      "treatment"  
> names(res$sample.type)
[1] "flower" "leaf"
> res$sample.type$flower
$breaks
[1]  0.01  0.03  0.10  0.30  1.00  3.00 10.00

$counts
[1]  4 10  1  0  1  6

$density
[1] 9.09090909 6.49350649 0.22727273 0.00000000 0.02272727 0.03896104

$mids
[1] 0.020 0.065 0.200 0.650 2.000 6.500

$xname
[1] "group$Feret"

$equidist
[1] FALSE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
>
```

You can format this into something that is suitable for plotting.

Comment: So this would be how to do it using apply. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we are not interested in the bins with no occurrences, we just need:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample.type, leaf.side, canopy, treatment, groups = cut(Feret, bins)) %>% 
  summarise(freq =n())
```

Output:

```
   sample.type leaf.side canopy treatment      groups freq
1       flower     upper    top     green  (0.03,0.1]    6
2       flower     upper    top     green   (0.1,0.3]    1
3       flower     upper    top     green       (1,3]    1
4       flower     upper    top     green      (3,10]    3
5       flower     upper    top     white (0.01,0.03]    4
6       flower     upper    top     white  (0.03,0.1]    4
7       flower     upper    top     white      (3,10]    3
8         leaf     lower bottom     white (0.01,0.03]    5
9         leaf     lower bottom     white  (0.03,0.1]    4
10        leaf     lower bottom     white   (0.1,0.3]    1
11        leaf     lower bottom     white     (0.3,1]    1
12        leaf     lower    top      grey (0.01,0.03]   10
13        leaf     lower    top      grey  (0.03,0.1]    1
14        leaf     upper bottom     white (0.01,0.03]    4
15        leaf     upper bottom     white  (0.03,0.1]    6
16        leaf     upper bottom     white   (0.1,0.3]    1
17        leaf     upper    top      blue (0.01,0.03]   10
18        leaf     upper    top      blue       (1,3]    1
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering how to deal with the zero counts.